# How to connect to bundle files?

Tags: arcgis-engine

I tiled my mxd document using the Multithreaded MapCruncher sample located here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000mm8000000

It appears to work, the output directory has different level directories, L0, L1... which contain .bundle files.

I don't know how to connect to these .bundle files.  I have looked at the DynamicCacheLayerManager, but that needs to be initialized with a layer file and the .bundle files are created with an MXD file which contains 1 or more layers (in my case 2 layers).  I tried it but it didn't work.   How can I connect to .bundle files?  I want my application to read these files and load the images instead of re-tiling the loaded maps.

I'm using ArcEngine 10 C# VS2010 Thanks in advance.

---

So I guess this page:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000mmm000000
says the following,

*Once the cache is finished processing, open Engine or Desktop, navigate to the cache folder, and add the cache as a raster.*

I tried using the "Open" button and the "Add Data" button and navigating to my .bundle files, but neither of these recognizes .bundles files.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that if you change this line

```
cacheStorageInfo.StorageFormat = esriMapCacheStorageFormat.esriMapCacheStorageModeCompact;
```

to this:

```
cacheStorageInfo.StorageFormat = esriMapCacheStorageFormat.esriMapCacheStorageModeExploded;
```

Then the cache will be something that you can connect to using the DynamicCacheLayerManager.

I will leave the question open for a bit because I would still like to know how to connect to bundles.

Answer (score 1):

Zach mentioned this...

> All ArcGIS clinets, including the web
>   APIs, will be able to read this file
>   format but custom coded or non-ESRI
>   software will not be able to read this
>   format. From the ArcGIS Server blog
>   post: ArcGIS clients, including the
>   Web APIs, know how to read the bundle
>   files produced by the compact cache
>   format. If you’ve coded your own logic
>   to pull tiles out of a virtual
>   directory, you should continue to use
>   the exploded format.
>
> The benefits of the Compact tile cache
>   are clear, but supported by ESRI-Only…

in his blog. My Geo Spatial.

Also some comments [here](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2010/09/13/ArcGIS-Server-10.0-improvements-to-map-cache-tile-generation.aspx) suggest you may need image server to publish through an MXD.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TileCannon](https://github.com/sainsb/tilecannon) , they've got it working.

I just tested it out myself and using bundles created on ArcGIS Server 10.2 I had to swap the row and column order inside the GetBundleTile function.

```
//var filename=Pad(bundle_filename_row.ToString("X"),z, "R")+Pad(bundle_filename_col.ToString("X"),z,"C");
var filename = Pad(bundle_filename_col.ToString("X"), z, "R") + Pad(bundle_filename_row.ToString("X"), z, "C");
```

Other than that it works a treat.

Comment: The latest bundle I just looked at had the row and columns in the original order so I'm not sure what what is going on with that..